# Increasing the number of records retrieved exponentially increases linq query duration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

During some testing of my data access routines using EF 5.0 and WCF Data Services, I have run into a performance issue. I am executing the following simple query from within a WCF Data Service Operation:

```
var addresses = (from address in context.Addresses select address).Take(500);
var addressList = addresses.ToList();
```

When I only take 500 records, query time is about 300 milliseconds. Taking 1000 records, query time is 4 seconds. Taking 2000 records query time is 24 seconds. Taking about 6000 records, query time is 360 seconds or more.

When I execute the sql statement generated by EF in Sql Server Management Studio, the 6000 record query is essentially instantaneous.

What settings can be configured to eliminate this performance issue?

Comment: If you don't need change tracking then you could try calling `.AsNoTracking()` on your `DbQuery` so you don't have overhead of the `ObjectStateManager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this  a read-only operation (e.g. to display in a grid) or do you need to update the entities you're retrieving from the database?

If you don't need to update the entities then you should use the [.AsNoTracking()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method - this means that Entity Framework won't try to keep track of any changes to the entities. Try something like this:

```
var addressList = context.Addresses.AsNoTracking().Take(500).ToList();
```

Recommended reading:

[Entity Framework and AsNoTracking](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/4/2/entity_framework_and_asnotracking)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but using AsNoTracking had no appreciable effect on the query execution time.  I believe the excessive time is being caused by some limited resources in EF or WCF Data Services, but I don't know which ones or how to reconfigure them.

Comment: Rui, I was mistaken. I re-ran my test with AsNoTracking and 2000 records only took 14 milliseconds.  Thanks for your help.